# Why failing to increase Chromium's priority and set it default internet browser in Debian?

Tags: dpkg, browser, alternatives

I want to set Chromium my default internet browser i.e. Chromium is being launched as the primary internet browser from other applications and that I do not receive the notification about *Chromium not being the default internet browser* at its startups. 
I think changing the priority to the highest and set it *default* internet browser can be the ways to do it. 
I am not sure what *manual*/*auto* are about in `update-alternatives` of internet browsers.

Fig. 1 My view when starting each time Chromium where it asks each time if it can be the default browser (Yes, I want it), but Chrome keeps being the default internet browser despite of the following attempts in `update-alternatives`

[image]

Before

```
root@masi:/home/masi# update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
There are 3 choices for the alternative gnome-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium               40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox-esr            70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: ^C
```

I do unsuccessfully where I try to increase Chromium's priority to 250

```
# http://askubuntu.com/a/620983/25388
root@masi:/home/masi# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser chromium 250
```

> update-alternatives: error: alternative path is not absolute as it should be: chromium

After (= Before)

```
root@masi:/home/masi# update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
There are 3 choices for the alternative gnome-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium               40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox-esr            70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
```

### Testing Grochmal's proposal

I run

```
root@masi:/home/masi# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium 250
```

> update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/chromium to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode

Privous log seems to be ok but not the output when seeing the priority

```
root@masi:/home/masi# update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
There are 3 choices for the alternative gnome-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium               40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox-esr            70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: ^C
```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel 4.6

Comment: `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium 250` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *Chrome overwrites my decision* ? Chromium *is* set as your default browser in Debian alternatives as shown above. No need to change priorities as they are only used when in `auto` mode, and not in `manual` mode which you use to explicitely force `chromium` (the entry marked with asterisk is one selected, which is cromium). You should explain in detail **what** you want to happen when you click on **what**, and **what** happens instead, and then maybe someone can help.

Comment: @Masi I **have** seen the body (three times now), and still it is not clear to me what you want.  You will have to be way more verbose, that is why I have **bolded** in my previous comment three things that are **the least** you have to explain in detail, as we can't read your mind what you mean by "default" (there are at least dozen different things what it can mean to you), "overwrite" etc.

Comment: @Masi that is not what I asked. Please clarify what *default* means to you in this case. Preferably in easy-to-uderstand form of  "**what** you want to happen when you click on **what**, and **what** happens instead". See http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise for details.

Comment: @MatijaNalis Please, see the body: *I want to set Chromium my default internet browser i.e. Chromium is being launched as the primary internet browser from other applications and that I do not receive the notification about `Chromium not being the default internet browser` at its startups.* - - I think the default internet browser is common term used in many Linux distributions so it should be clear to the reader what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several (unrelated) questions in this, depending on definition of *default*; and each of those has its own solutions.

- for launching in *Desktop Environment*, browser which will be started is usually specified in Debian alternatives system as stated in question (and is already set to Chromium!).
- of course if user has created shortcut to specific app instead of `x-www-browser` then alternatives won't be used and shortcut need to changed manually according to that *DE*
- for opening from certain programs (like *MUA*s), attachments will be opened according to `mailcap(5)`, see that manual page how to override for example `text/html` etc. (See also `/etc/mime.types` for maping local extensions to MIME types)
- some apps will use `xdg-open(1)` for determining with what to open files.
- other apps yet will have its own lists (for example, in `Firefox` you'll have `about:preferences#content` URL to configure with what to open some MIME type, in `mc` you'll have *Menu / Command / Edit extension file* to determune what happens when you click on `.html` file etc)
- For the `Chromium not being the default internet browser` message, disable broken check in *Menu / Settings / Settings / Default browser* or see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688779)

Comment: *MUA* = *Mail User Agent*. - - Great work flow for the question! So I just disabled the notice by the way your last point describes.